# unescape jquery encoded by application

Tags: jquery, html

I wrote a piece of Jquery to hide certain tables on an HTML page. Works fine, however the application I am using escapes tags in Jquery causing it not to function. Can you help me?

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
for (var i=2;i<1000;i++){
       $('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + i + ') > td > table').each(function() {      
            $(this).hide(); 
            });
         }
     });
```

Code generated by the application after form is generated:

```
<script> $(document).ready(function() {
for (var i=2;i&lt;1000;i++){

           $(&#39;table&gt; tbody &gt; tr:nth-child(&#39; + i + &#39;) &gt; td &gt; table&#39;).each(function() {  

    $(this).hide(); 
                          });
                  }
           }); </script>
```

I tried to use an "unescape" function but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Why is your server encoding this script?  Why is it not included in a static js file include for the page?

Comment: I tried using a js file, but the application still encodes it. The HTML file is a template which gets populated by a report generator. I unfortunately don't have any influence on the application behavior

Comment: Your saying that your server is encoding static js files?

Comment: The application is obviously trying to prevent XSS injection. You shouldn't be using that to generate executable code, since it's designed for user-generated content.